# Mysql : performance of update with primary key and extra wheres, will it be slower?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, where-clause

Let's say I have a table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bar1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bar2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And I have two queries:

```
update Foo set bar1=10 where id=5000;
```

```
update Foo set bar1=10 where id=5000 and bar1=0;
```

My guess is that the second query will not run slower than the first query but I need confirmation from someone with certainty knowledge.

(The reason I want to do the second is that when multiple clients select the table first and then update them simultaneously only one people will be able to update successfully)

Comment: add and index on id and bar1, to make it only barely sloqwe

Comment: *My guess is that the second query will not run slower than the first query* If all rows to be updated by 1st query matches `bar1=0` then both queries will take approximately the same time (I doubt that the difference can be detected). If not then 2nd query is faster - simply due to less rows to be written. But `id` is PK, only one row will be updated, and there is no difference - additional comparing is too fast to be detected.

Comment: if we write multiple conditions in a query it will get selected result that will be obvious less then updating complete table so that much less will be result it will take less time to update table so yes you right second one will take some less time to update.

Comment: Thank you all for the confirmation.

Comment: @nbk - `INDEX(id, bar1)` would _slow it down_!  This is because the index needs to be updated when the update succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the row.  The Optimizer will look at the possible indexes (just the PK) and decide to start with `id=5000`.  There is at most one such row.
2. (for the second case) verify that `bar1=0`.  If not, the query is finished.
3. Check to see if there is anything to change -- is `bar1` already set to 10?  If so, finish.
4. Do the work of updating -- this involves saving the existing row in case of a `ROLLBACK`, tentatively storing the new value, etc, etc. -- This step is likely to be the most costly step.

Step 2 is the only difference -- and it is a quite small step.  It is *not* worth worrying about when it comes to performance.

On the other hand, Step 2 means that the two Updates are different -- What should happen if `bar1=4567`?  The first Update would change it, but the second won't.

Your final comment implies that *maybe* you should be using transactions to keep one client from stepping on another.  Perhaps the code should be more like:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... WHERE id = 5000  FOR UPDATE;
decide what to do -- which might include ROLLBACK and exit
UPDATE Foo SET bar1=10 WHERE id = 5000;
COMMIT;
```

Bottom Line:  Use transactions, not extra code, to deal with concurrency.

Caveat:  A transaction should be "fast" (less than a few seconds).  If you need a "long" transaction (eg, a 'shopping cart' that could take minutes to finish), a different mechanism is needed.  If you need a long transaction, start a new question explaining the situation.  (The current question is discussing the performance of a single Update.)

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Actually I used transaction but begins after select in  order to minimize server waiting time. I thought that the result will be the same but I think putting select out of the transaction and adding an extra check in update will lead to faster response when access frequency is very high. Is my assumption actually true?

Comment: @cr001 - If you need to perform any logic before deciding to do the Update, you need the transaction.  If you can blindly do the Update, then autocommit=ON suffices.  I brought up the transaction because you mentioned a Select before the Update.  Note that the `FOR UPDATE` is necessary.

Comment: Wouldn't that lock the table when you do the select (so that other people will need to wait for the lock when select starts)? My assumption is that if I do the select outside the transaction then one only needs to wait for the lock when updating and therefore waiting time can be saved. Is this not the case in reality?

Comment: @cr001 - With `ENGINE=InnoDB`, the _row_ is locked, not the _whole table_.  If two connections are locking the _same_ row, you _need_ the locking; it's worth the price.  If the Select and Update are in separate transactions, someone could sneak in between.

Comment: Indeed I was assuming the whole table was going to be locked. Thank you so much for the clarification.